# Symfony security, too many redirects

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to set up security and authentication, I tried to follow the symfony tutorial, but now when I try to access any page I get `localhost redirected you too many times.` I want to get redirected to login page if you are not logged in and accessing secured page.

This is my security.yml file

security:

```
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded

encoders:
    Akon\UserBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt



providers:
    akon:
        entity:
            class: AkonUserBundle:User


firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        provider: akon
        form_login:
            login_path:    akon_user_login
            check_path:    akon_user_login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /              


access_control:
    # require ROLE_ADMIN for /register*
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Akon/UserBundle/resources/config/routing.yml

```
akon_user_homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AkonUserBundle:Default:index }

akon_user_register:
    path:     /register
    defaults: { _controller: AkonUserBundle:Default:Register}

akon_user_login:
    path:     /login
    defaults: { _controller: AkonUserBundle:Security:Login}


logout:
    path: /logout
```

Comment: Think you might need anonymous: true http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/security.html#authentication-and-firewalls-i-e-getting-the-user-s-credentials

Comment: Try uncomment `#- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }`

Comment: Ops, sorry forgot to comment. The first answer was right after I added annoymous: true, it works normal.